# Captcha doesn't display with custom header security policy referrer-policy: none

Tags: google-chrome, captcha, referrer-policy

I am facing an issue of using below captcha package, 
id="CaptchaMvc.Mvc4" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net45"

Issue description - While applying the custom header security policy - referrer policy value 'none', it doesn't show captcha on Chrome but showing on IE/Edge for application https URL. Changing the referrer policy other than value 'none' it shows the captcha on Chrome for application URL.
how to rectify this?

Comment: Any resolution?

Comment: can anybody look into?